# Measurability of $t \mapsto \chi_{\{x \mid u(t)(x) \geq C\}}(x)$

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, bochner-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded domain and let $u = L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$. Is the map
$$t \mapsto \chi_{\{x \mid u(t)(x) \geq C\}}(x)$$
measurable for a constant $C$? Here $\chi$ is the indicator function.

I am not sure how the measurability of the set in the indicator function comes into it, since we are concerned about measurability over $t$.

Comment: With which domain/codomain are you considering this function? I.e. is $x$ fixed, or are you considering $\chi_{\dots}(x)$ as a function (e.g. in $L^2(\Omega)$)?

Comment: @PhoemueX Hmm. I want to show that $\chi_{\cdots}$ is in $L^2(0,T;L^2(\Omega))$, so I need the map $t \mapsto \chi_{\cdots}$ to be measurable, hence this question... I guess $x$ is fixed?